# Prove that $\sin z = 0 \Rightarrow z = n\pi, n\in\mathbb Z$. Where did I make a mistake?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

What it says in the title. I've got the proof mostly down, but I must have made an error somewhere in my ''calculations'', as I'm getting $x = \frac{n\pi} 2$ for the real part of the complex number $z = x + \mathrm i y$.

### My work is as follows:

\begin{align}
       &&\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i z} - \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i z}} {2\mathrm i} &= 0\\
\iff &&\mathrm e^{\mathrm i z} - \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i z} &= 0\\
\iff &&\mathrm e^{\mathrm i z}  &= \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i z}\\
\iff &&\mathrm e^{\mathrm i (x + \mathrm i y)}  &= \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i (x + \mathrm i y)}\\
\iff &&\mathrm e^{-y + \mathrm i x}  &= \mathrm e^{y - \mathrm i x}\\
\iff &&\mathrm e^{-y}\Big( \cos x + \mathrm i \sin x \Big) &= \mathrm e^{y}\Big( \cos x - \mathrm i \sin x \Big)\\
\iff &&\frac{ \cos x + \mathrm i \sin x }{ \cos x - \mathrm i \sin x }  &= \mathrm e^{2y}\\
\iff &&\frac{ (\cos x + \mathrm i \sin x)^2 }{ (\cos x - \mathrm i \sin x)(\cos x + \mathrm i \sin x) }  &= \mathrm e^{2y}\\
\iff &&\frac{ (\cos x + \mathrm i \sin x)^2 }{ \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x }  &= \mathrm e^{2y}\\
\iff &&\frac{ (\cos x + \mathrm i \sin x)^2 }{ 1 }  &= \mathrm e^{2y}\\
\iff &&(\cos x + \mathrm i \sin x)^2  &= \mathrm e^{2y}\\
\iff &&\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x + 2\mathrm i \cos x \sin x  &= \mathrm e^{2y},
\end{align}

Now the imaginary part of this should be zero for the equation to hold,
meaning
\begin{equation}
2\sin x \cos x =\sin 2x = 0 \iff x = \frac {n\pi} 2\ldots
\end{equation}

Not what I wanted to see. So, where did I make a mistake? I can't seem to spot it, to no great surprise.

Comment: A suggestion - $e^{iz}=e^{-iz}\;\Rightarrow\; e^{2iz}=1\Rightarrow\; ?$

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe Well played, sir.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe That shortens the calculations, but it leaves me with the same requisite condition, that $\sin(2x)$ should be zero.

Comment: We have that $e^{2n\pi}=1\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: It is, but the question (whose title I just clarified) was specifically about the reason as to why the steps I made lead to an incorrect answer. This actually bothers me. :/

Comment: Is there any constraint on the value $\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x?$

Comment: Well, my reasoning restricts the value of $x$ so in that sense, yes there is. If only I got the value of $x$ right, the correct value of $y=0$ would pop out of the equation $\mathrm e^{2y} = \cos^2x - \sin^2 x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x = \frac{n\pi}2$. If $n$ is odd, we have $\cos x = 0$ and $\sin x = 1$. In this case, the equation
$$\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x + 2i \cos x \sin x  = e^{2y}$$
simplifies to
$$-1  = e^{2y},$$
which is impossible since the right-hand side is positive.

Therefore $n$ is even.